# how to prevent getting same name with different ID on mysql Java

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to display all the data on a table, table is fine . The problem I'm having is preventing same name with different ID. here is my code

```
private void AddbtActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    String id = idFld.getText() ;
    String item = ADDfld.getText();
    String amount = AMOUNTfld.getText();
          try {

    con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/isdb","root","");

   String query = "Insert into item (id,NAME,AMOUNT) values (?,?,?)";

     pst = con.prepareStatement(query);

      pst.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(id));
     pst.setString(2, item);
     pst.setString(3,amount);
      pst.execute();

} catch (SQLException ex ) {

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);

 }

        ADDfld.setText("");
         idFld.setText("");
        AMOUNTfld.setText("");
        updateCombo();
         update_Table();
```

I tried to create data but it does allow same name with different ID which is what I'm trying to prevent

[image]

Any idea how to prevent this? Please help.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want more than one product with same name in your table then, you can add a `unique` constraint on name column, e.g.:

```
ALTER TABLE items ADD CONSTRAINT name UNIQUE (name);
```

This will prevent inserts with duplicate name, resulting in `MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException`.

Another way to do is to check whether the item exists, before allowing user to inser the item, e.g.:

```
SELECT count(*) as count FROM items WHERE name = ?
```

If the count is more than zero, you can show appropriate error message to the user.